# Why is need Propagation.MANDATORY with PESSIMISTIC_WRITE?

Tags: java, database, jpa, locking, spring-transactions

There is such an example.
Do I understand correctly, without `MANDATORY` this function will mislead the developer?
In the sense that without a transaction, despite the name, the locking will not be performed.

```
interface EmployeRepository extends JpaRepository<Employe, String> {

    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.MANDATORY)
    @Lock(LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE)
    Optional<Employe> findWriteLockedById(String id);
}
```

Comment: `Propagation.MANDATORY` just means that this function needs to run within an already existing transaction. Spring will throw an exception if it's not already in a transaction.

Comment: Yes, I understand. But I have a question specifically about this example.

Comment: Your question isn't clear. Without the transaction being propagated; if the Find call is in its own transaction (or not in one) the lock will be released as soon as the method returns. This can be useful if you want to check that no other processes hold a lock on the object, but not if you are trying to ensure it won't change out from under the read.